# how to refactor the map convert operation

Tags: java

I wrote a logic about converting the basic map to another structure map, however SonarLint comments it need to refactor, here is codes:

```
public static Map<List<String>, String> toStockMap(List<Map<String, Object>> rows) {
    Map<List<String>, String> stockMap = new HashMap<>();
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(rows)) {
        return stockMap;
    }
    for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
        String stock = null;
        String itemId = null;
        String modelId = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> cell : row.entrySet()) {
            if (cell.getKey().equals("stock")) {
                stock = cell.getValue().toString();
            }
            if (cell.getKey().equals("itemid")) {
                itemId = cell.getValue().toString();
            }
            if (cell.getKey().equals("modelid")) {
                modelId = cell.getValue().toString();
            }
        }
        if (stock != null && itemId != null && modelId != null) {
            stockMap.put(Arrays.asList(modelId, itemId), stock);
        }
    }
    return stockMap;
}
```

and below as sonarlint comment:
[image: sonarlint]

how should I improve it? thanks

Comment: which part is line 71?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't need to enumerate the `row` entrySet to check for the presence of keys. You could simplify that considerably, something like

```
for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
    Object stock = row.get("stock");
    Object itemId = row.get("itemid");
    Object modelId = row.get("modelid");
    if (stock != null && itemId != null && modelId != null) {
        stockMap.put(Arrays.asList(modelId.toString(), itemId.toString()), 
                stock.toString());
    }
}
```