# How to refactor and reduce this complex logic including too many if-else

Tags: java

there is a segment codes I wanna to refactor as sonarlint always comments "Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 32 to the 15 allowed", below as code:

```
for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
        String name = "";
        String shopId = "";
        String promotionId = "";
        String itemId = "";
        String modelId = "";
        String country = "";
        Long promotionStartTime = null;
        Long promotionEndTime = null;
        List<MetricEntity> metricEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> cell : row.entrySet()) {
            if (cell.getKey().equals(ITEMNAME)) {
                name = cell.getValue().toString();
            } else if (cell.getKey().equals(SHOPID)) {
                shopId = cell.getValue().toString();
                metricEntities.add(MetricEntity.builder().id(codeToMetric.get(cell.getKey()).getId())
                        .code(cell.getKey()).value(cell.getValue()).build());
            } else if (cell.getKey().equals("country")) {
                country = cell.getValue().toString();
                metricEntities.add(MetricEntity.builder().id(codeToMetric.get(cell.getKey()).getId())
                        .code(cell.getKey()).value(cell.getValue()).build());
            } else if (cell.getKey().equals("promotionid")) {
                promotionId = cell.getValue().toString();
                FlashSaleEntity startFlashSale = promotionIdToFlashSale
                        .get(Long.valueOf(cell.getValue().toString()));
                if (startFlashSale != null) {
                    promotionStartTime = startFlashSale.getStartTime();
                }
                FlashSaleEntity endFlashSale = promotionIdToFlashSale.get(Long.valueOf(cell.getValue().toString()));
                if (endFlashSale != null) {
                    promotionEndTime = endFlashSale.getEndTime();
                }
            } else {
                if (cell.getKey().equals(ITEMID)) {
                    itemId = cell.getValue().toString();
                }
                if (cell.getKey().equals("modelid")) {
                    modelId = cell.getValue().toString();
                }
                metricEntities.add(MetricEntity.builder().id(codeToMetric.get(cell.getKey()).getId())
                        .code(cell.getKey()).value(cell.getValue()).build());
            }
        }
        List<MetricEntity> flashSaleItemMetrics = flashSaleItemMetricsMap
                .get(Arrays.asList(shopId, promotionId, itemId, modelId));
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(flashSaleItemMetrics)) {
            metricEntities.addAll(flashSaleItemMetrics);
        }
        products.add(ProductEntity.builder().id(itemId).shopId(shopId).region(country)
                .promotionId(Long.valueOf(promotionId)).promotionStartTime(promotionStartTime)
                .promotionEndTime(promotionEndTime).name(name).metrics(metricEntities).build());}
```

*the structure of rows is List< Map < String, Object>>.* How to improve that to avoid SonarLint commenting?

Comment: Assuming your code already works, your question might fit better on our sister site [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).  Off the top of head, you might be able to use a `switch` statement inside of the many if else blocks.

Comment: what is your java version?

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57863532/2970947). Why did you iterate the `entrySet()` to match keys in a loop *again*?

Comment: because there are some keyNames in the map can't be known beforehand, so there need be a if...else statement to handle them

Comment: @Santos java8.0 version

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it can work well, and switch statement can't improve the SonarLint situation

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but thank you for telling me about the sister site, I will ask it in there